# Error Django polls app command makemigration polls

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am facing an error each time I run this command as django beginner when creating polls up I don't know if I am missing something please refer it back to me I really need help.

```
py manage.py makemigrations polls






Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\4488\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\4488\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\4488\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\4488\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\4488\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create      
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\4488\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 970, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'; 'polls.apps' is not a package
```

Comment: You'll have to give use more information to help you debug, for example your directory structure. But your first issue seems to be that you miscopied `'polls.apps.PollsConfig'` from the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models)  as `polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango`.

Comment: Yes that's exactly where I am facing the problems.

Comment: So yes guide me through.

Comment: Fix your miscopy and check what output you get then.

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem.

Comment: What I did was I only added installed apps ' 'polls.apps.PollsConfig' but that's not the case you have to create two seperate installed apps each containing same dotted path but the difference is that you have to include the last one the one you should be copying to this ''polls.apps.PollsConfig'.

Comment: The problem was probably a missing comma after `'polls.apps.PollsConfig'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.